# Illegally crossing Hungarian border

Tags: international, european-union

Recently I read [this article](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2015/09/16/raw-video-total-chaos-erupts-at-hungary-border-as-armed-mob-of-illegal-immigrants-clash-with-riot-police/) with the following quote:

> But Hungary acted this week to stop the huge flow of people, sealing off its border with Serbia with a razor-wire fence and **making it a crime to enter the country illegally**.

I'm wondering why it was not a crime previously to cross the borders illegally. If this was not a crime, doesn't this made crossing the borders illegally an "*empty box*"?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I would think this opposed the free movement of people, a fundamental freedom of the EU contracts.

Comment: @sebix: but Serbia is not part of the EU. In that perspective the Hungarian-Serbian border is a border of the EU as well. So you are not moving *within* the EU.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about Slovenia, sry. And that fence is already being removed or it's in progress.

Answer (score 3):

In the US it is not a crime to be in the country illegally.

> As a general rule, it is not a crime for a removable alien to remain in the United States.

[Arizona v US](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-182b5e1.pdf)

So it's illegal, you get a state induced consequence (deportation) but it doesn't make you a criminal e.g. you don't go to jail for it.

I have no idea if that's what's going on over there but it's a plausible explanation.

Comment: *Being* in the country illegally may not be a crime under US law.  *Entering* the country illegally, however, is (and that's what this question is about).  See [8 USC 1325 (a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1325), describing the crime usually called "illegal entry".  It's a Class B misdemeanor, I believe.

Comment: The question was about the EU and especially Hungary, not the US. That's a totally other jurisdiction.

Comment: @sebix yes, you totally missed the point. I was providing an example of something which is illegal but not criminal.

Answer (score 0):

I would put that down to bad wording of the article. As you mention it would be a crime if you did anything illegally.

Comment: That is not true. Many things that are illegal without being a crime. Breaking a contract is illegal; it's not a crime.

Comment: @DaleM is illegal really the correct word to describe breaking a contract. I think of illegal as something that violates a law or rule; something with a government-enforceable repercussion. If you break a contract the state doesn't care. However there are other non-criminal activity that are illegal and open us up to sanction by the government. Like violating a building code.

Comment: @jqning illegal simply means contrary to the law; breaking a contract is contrary to the law